# Getting ASCII from char not working?

Tags: java, ascii

I am creating a ticketing system that follows the following format:

> Write a Java program called Ticket.java that prompts (asks) the user
>   to enter a ticket number. The format of a valid ticket is CCCDD[C][C]
>   where D = a digit and C = a character and [C] means that the character
>   at this position is optional. The three characters at the start may be
>   any characters (letters). If there is only one optional character at
>   the end of the ticket String, then that character may only be 'S' or
>   'M' If there are two optional characters at the end of the ticket
>   String, then the characters can only be 'S' and 'M' in that order.

An example input is LMN25S

Now to get the price i must format the **first three characters** into ASCII, add them together and compare to be rule(s) below.

> If the first three characters are "less than" JKL, the base price is
>   $50, if the first three characters are "greater than or equal to" JKL
>   and "less than" TAF, the base price is $100, else the base price, is
>   $150

The problem is, the questions guidelines(above) state that price must be 100$ if the item is smaller than TAF but equal or larger to JKL. but those items equal the following:

```
    char j = 'J';char k = 'K';char l = 'L';
    int JKL = (int)j + (int)k + (int)l;
    char t = 'T';char a = 'A';char f = 'F';
    int TAF = (int)t + (int)a + (int)f;
    Print("JKL:" + JKL + "\nTAF:" + TAF);
```

Prints JKL:225, TAF:219 thus making the rules null as TAF is, according to how im converting, smaller.

Here is my whole code for a better understanding

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ticket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Print("Please enter a ticket number:");
        String ticket = getInput();
        if(countValid(ticket) && checkCharacters(ticket) && checkDigits(ticket) && checkLastCharacter(ticket)) {
            Print("Valid!");
            Print("Ticket pricing is " + PrintPrice(ticket));
        }
    }

    public static double PrintPrice(String input) {
        int first = (int)input.charAt(0);
        Print("" + first);
        int second = (int)input.charAt(1);
        Print("" + second);
        int third = (int)input.charAt(2);
        Print("" + third);
        double price = 0;
        Print("Total:" + (first+second+third) + "");
        //225
        char j = 'J';char k = 'K';char l = 'L';
        int JKL = (int)j + (int)k + (int)l;
        char t = 'T';char a = 'A';char f = 'F';
        int TAF = (int)t + (int)a + (int)f;
        Print("JKL:" + JKL + "\nTAF" + TAF);

        char one = input.charAt(0);
        char two = input.charAt(1);
        char three = input.charAt(2);

        int value = (int)one + (int)two + (int)three;
        Print("next total:" + value);
        if(value < JKL) {
            price += 50;
        }else if(value >= JKL && value < TAF) {
            price += 100;
        }else{
            price += 150;
        }
        String discountString = "" + Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(3)) + Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(4));
        Print(discountString);
        if(input.length() > 5) {
            if(input.charAt(5) == 'S') {
                price+= 17.45;
            }else if(input.charAt(5) == 'M') {
                price+=29.70;
            }
        }else if(input.length() > 6) {
            //price+=41.25;
        }

        double discount = Double.parseDouble(discountString);
        Print((price * (discount/100)) + "");
        //price = price - (price * (discount/100));
        //price = price * factor;
        return price;
    }


    public static boolean checkLastCharacter(String input) {
        boolean success = false;
        int successCount = 0;
        if(input.length() == 5) {
            success = true;
        }else{
            if(input.length() == 6) {
                char temp = input.charAt(5);
                if(temp == 'S' || temp == 'M') {
                    success = true;
                }else{
                    success = false;
                    Print("Failed due to character not matching 'S' or 'M', '" + temp + "' is invalid");
                }
            }else if(input.length() == 7) {
                char temp = input.charAt(5);
                char temp1 = input.charAt(6);
                if(temp == 'S' && temp1 == 'M') {
                    success = true;
                }else{
                    success = false;
                    Print("Failed due to characters not matching 'SM', '" + temp + temp1 + "' is invalid");
                }
            }else{
                Print("Input characters overloaded! Only accepts up to 7 inputs");
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    public static boolean countValid(String input) {
        boolean success = false;
        if(input.length() < 9 && input.length() > 4) {
            success = true;
        }else{
            Print("The count is invalid, only numbers between 5 and 7 are accepted!");
        }
        return success;
    }

    public static boolean checkCharacters(String input) {
        boolean success = false;
        int successCount = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            char temp = input.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isLetter(temp)) {
                successCount++;
            }
        }
        if(successCount == 2) {
            success = true;
        }else{
            Print("First three characters must be letters!");
        }
        return success;
    }

    public static boolean checkDigits(String input) {
        boolean success = false;
        int successCount = 0;
        for(int i = 3; i < 5; i++) {
            char temp = input.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isDigit(temp)) {
                successCount++;
            }
        }
        if(successCount == 2) {
            success = true;
        }else{
            Print("The inputs after 3 letters must be 2 digits!");
        }
        return success;
    }

    //Easier way to print to system.out
    public static void Print(String input) {
        System.out.println(input);
    }

    //Gets the input from a scanner
    public static String getInput() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        return sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Please ignore all the various prints, just for testing purposes. Is my conversion correct or is the questions rules correct and I have miss-converted/miss-formated

Edit: full problem statement below for help:

> The user may enter a ticket String of any length. The valid length of
>   a ticket is between 5 and 7 depending on the conditions above. Any
>   ticket that is not in this length range is automatically invalid. A
>   ticket that is invalid for any reason will result in a message being
>   displayed to the screen saying that the ticket is invalid, and no
>   processing will be done with that ticket. This includes not showing
>   any cost. Every effort should be made to give the exact reason why the
>   ticket is invalid. For example, wrong length, starts with an invalid
>   character, or ends with an invalid character. These are not the only
>   reasons why a ticket is invalid, part of your task is to list all the
>   conditions that make a ticket invalid and write code to cover those
>   cases. After checking the length of the user input, your program needs
>   to check that the first three characters in the String are indeed
>   letters ('A' - 'Z' and/or 'a' - 'z', user input must be case
>   insensitive). If anyone of the first three characters are not letters,
>   then an appropriate error message is displayed to the screen and the
>   program closes. After this check is cleared, then your program must
>   check that the next 2 characters in the String are indeed digits
>   (between 0 - 9 ). Again, if there are not 2 digits, then the program
>   displays an appropriate error message and closes. Hint: consider that
>   when we enter 0 at the keyboard we are entering the character '0' 
>   which has an ASCII/Unicode of 48. So what we are really storing is the
>   base 10 number 48. We need to convert this from character 0 to integer
>   0. 1 is actually  character '1' with ASCII/Unicode v
>   alue 49 and so on. f the ticket is valid, then the cost of the ticket
>   is calculated and displayed to the screen. If the first three
>   characters are "less than" JKL, the base price is $50, if the first
>   three characters are "greater than or equal to" JKL and "less than"
>   TAF, the base price is $100, else the base price, is $150 The 2 digit
>   characters have to be converted into a base 10 integer. This is the
>   discount to be applied to the final cost of the ticket. If the 2
>   digits were, for example, 25 then this would be converted in to the
>   base 10 number twenty-five. This would mean that there is a 25%
>   discount on the final ticket price, final meaning after we have
>   processed the 'S' and/or 'M' optional characters, if they are present.
>   The character 'M' at the end of the ticket String, if it is the only
>   optional character adds $29.70 to the cost, of the ticket. The
>   character 'S' at the end of the ticket String, if it is the only
>   optional character adds $17.45 to the cost, of the ticket. The
>   characters 'S' and 'M', in that order, if there are the optional
>   characters at the end of the ticket String add $41.25 to the cost, of
>   the ticket.

Comment: 210 is greater than 178 but 2+1+0 = 3 is smaller than 1+7+8 = 16. JKL is smaller than TAF because J < T. It is also most likely to be alphabetic order other than ASCII value

Comment: Where are you getting 178?

Comment: nowhere. Just an arbitrary example to point out that different position of digits may convert to different values

Answer (score 2):

Maybe they are talking about the lexicographic order, not the sum of the char?

Then JFK is inferior to TAF and PAM = 100$.

In that case, you just need to compare the string:
(thanks @Serge Ballesta for the answer)

```
// to upperCase is a safety to match the case insensitiv requirement
String priceString = input.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
double price;
if (priceString.compareTo("JKL") < 0){
    price = 50.;
}
else if (priceString.compareTo("TAF") < 0){
    price = 100.;
}
else{
    price = 150.;
}
```

Don't forget about the discount (the digit) and the last two char.
Good luck!

Comment: compareTo (that uses lexographic) doesnt produce meaningful results after testing so it seems unlikely its that

Comment: Updated the problem statement, as you can see it offers a hint that talks about ASCII compared to numbers

Comment: I see no hint about ASCII value there...only the digit must be converted

Comment: Hint: consider that when we enter 0 at the keyboard we are entering the character '0' which has an ASCII/Unicode of 48. So what we are really storing is the base 10 number 48. We need to convert this from character 0 to integer 0. 1 is actually character '1' with ASCII/Unicode v alue 49 and so on.

use ctrl+F to find the hint in my original post, i know its a big paragraph of inproperly spaced text but its there

Comment: nah, that is ok, because you are converting number, but there is no mention of converting letters.
(btw you can also to Integer.parseint() to convert the number)

Comment: What I mean is that in your statement, they never talked about how to compare the char. They just talk about how to process the numbers.
As first instinct, I would go to the alphabet order, because it matches the statement about TAF being greater than JFK.

Comment: But its a hint, not exactly what to do. it is telling us how to point a set of letters to a set of numbers to compare no? and using Integer.parseInt only takes strings that are valid as an int. aka 10, not 'JKL' or alike. not sure about chars but i doubt it would allow it either

Comment: It would not allow it indeed.
It's quite a confusing hint I guess, I would recommend not to apply it on the first three caracters. The logic is not hard so you can still change it latter.

Comment: Im re-visiting lexographic and seeing how I go, i think you are indeed correct. despite it not mentioning it in the damn problem statement I think i can make it work with that, will post results

Comment: @Whitefret: you gave the correct answer before I did, but yours still looks like a comment. You should improve it (feel free to copy parts or code from mine) and I'll upvote it.

Comment: It is now a better answer :-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am quite new to writing answer here, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The full requirement is clear and I have seldom seen such nice specs in a SO question.

You are asked to convert the 2 digits to an integer value, but you shall compare the *string* CCC to `"JKL"` and `"TAF"` after making it uppercase (*user input must be case insensitive*)

So yes @Whitefret guess is correct. And the test should simply be:

```
    String priceString = input.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
    double price;
    if (priceString.compareTo("JKL") < 0) {
        price = 50.;
    }
    else if (priceString.compareTo("TAF") < 0) {
        price = 100.;
    }
    else {
        price = 150.;
    }
```

Where on earth did you see that you were asked to add ascii values ?

And read again the specs for the discount: *The 2 digit characters have to be converted into a base 10 integer. This is the discount to be applied to the final cost of the ticket. If the 2 digits were, for example, 25 then this would be converted in to the base 10 number twenty-five*

So what is needed is just:

```
int discount = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(3, 5));
```

TL/DR: **You must read and understand your requirements before coding**

Comment: Ah, I just got to the same conclusion after @Whitefret proposed it, I originally ignored it becuase the hint threw me off as well as my inexperience with using lexicographically sorting. I am fine with the digit item to base 10, the hint just confused me. thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the discount? i did it a different way

Answer (score 0):

Is it a simple concatenation?

T=84, A=65, F=70 -- so TAF = 846,570 
J=74, k=75, L=76 -- so JKL = 747,576

Comment: It doesnt say to use multiplication, but that may be correct

Comment: That's not multiplication. I simply converted the chars to their ASCII values and concatenated the resulting digits.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a more precise definition of the "less than" and "greater than" bits of the specification. My guess would be the same as @Whitefret's that it might be a lexicographic order but you should make sure of that.

Comment: Yeah I will ask, and from what im attempting lex order seems to be the way, just terrible wording for an assingment that threw me, who was reasonable comfortable with my ability in my current uni year, to handle. the way its given everything else out in baby steps, forcing us to make assumptions in the assignment is bizzare

Comment: In comparision to what you normally get as requirements in real live projects, your assignment is pretty much perfect :-)

Answer (score -1):

So after doing some research it looks like it was indeed lexographical order.
So I got the three possible variables and sorted them with Arrays.sort and then picked the middle and checked it.

```
 String[] array = new String[] {"JKL", "TAF", input.substring(0,3)};
        Arrays.sort(array);
        String result = array[1];
        if(result=="JKL") {
            price+=50;
        }else if(result=="TAF") {
            price+=150;
        }else{
            price+=100;
        }
```

Comment: Avoid using `==` when comparing strings. It can work here since you actually compare string constants but you should always use `equals` method.